# Average of the normal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

I was trying to solve this exercice , but I asked my self , why and how to find out the average normal force , since we can get directly the average normal force ? , because when the ball touches the surface we automaticaly get : $N = P = m.g~~$ isn'it  ? So why to search an average force since we can directly get the force itself ?

Comment: I am not totally sure what the exercise is calling normal force. Most probably they are referring to the effective force which is causing the ball to not reach the full height after the bounce. As you have a contact time you can use energy conservation to calculate an effective force which is slowing down the ball. But why call it normal force, as it is parallel to all vectors in this exercise.

Comment: @user_na: Energy conservation in this case will be difficult, because the energy is being lost to the elastic deformation of the ball. I suspect momentum conservation (as the answer by FrodCube demonstrates) is the only way to do this. Also, the normal force always acts perpendicularly to a surface, which would be the force the floors acts on the ball with in this case.

Comment: @levitopher, ahh now I get the question :-) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The normal force is not simply given by $N = mg$ because the ball is not just resting on the surface. When the ball is far away there is no force, when the ball touches the surface it will be pushed a bit but the ball will keep going down but slowing down until it stops and then the force will keep pushing the ball making it move upwards and bounce away.

Basically you need to calculate the impulse (how much the momentum change) because that's equal to the contact time times the average normal force.

$\Delta J = N_{avg}T = (p_f - p_i)$

You can get $p_f$ and $p_i$ from energy conservation.